# Is it possible to force urllib to just fetch plain html, not images, scripts, etc?

Tags: python, urllib

I am using `urllib` to crawl data from the web.  I am trying to fetch different pages of a website which exactly use same template, images and `JS` codes(e.g. different users profile). The problem is that the template images and scripts are so heavy and I don't need them. The only thing that I care about is the plain `HTML` of the page.

Is there any way to force the `urllib` to fetch plain `HTML` only or at least perform a good caching mechanism from python code?

Comment: Ah...`urllib` and `requests` both doesn't run *any* JS code. Also they don't download the images. If you just want to get the part of HTML code which you want, without the template part, then I'd suggest use [**BeautifulSoup**](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) parse the HTML code.

Comment: `urllib` *will* download only HTML without any intervention. You have to put extra effort into it to make it download the extra stuff. So... what code do you have now? Does it download more than HTML? Or is this just a theoretical question?

Comment: @zvone that is great. I have imagined that it behaves differently. I will accept your comment if you provide it as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, `urllib` will download only HTML without any intervention.

In order to download other resources (images, scripts, stylesheets), you would have to parse the downloaded HTML and initiate download of each yourself.

So, to answer your question, you don't have to do anything special. Just do this:

```
html = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could ask what the return type of a given URL by using [HEAD](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec5.html#sec5.1.1) HTTP method. Thus you would get all the actual headers of the response, but without the response body. Then you should analyze the response headers and decide whether you need to save the response and repeat the request with ordinal GET/POST methods.

To perform a `HEAD` request you may use [httplib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/httplib.html#examples)